# NSTableview: a list of supported registerForDraggedTypes?

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, directory, tableview

Where can I find a document on which are the supported registerForDraggedTypes?

More specifically, I would like to limit it to only accept folders (not files), and get the folder's path. Which type I should go with?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In modern times, the types in question should be UTIs, so you'll want to look at the [Uniform Type Identifiers Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/), which contains [a list of the system-declared UTIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html).